# what are some circumstances that can cause vscode python debugger to be slow or deadlock?

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

What are some reasons that can cause the vscode debugger to be slow? Any speculations or link to vscode limitation would be great.

I'm currently creating sliding windows with numpy array using `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`

And for some reason in a specific section of the code the debugger just fails to compute large sliding windows.

```
len(df) > 10*24*60
win_size = 240
sliding_win = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(df.values,(win_size,len(df.columns)))
```

what is weird is that when i ran it without the debugger, it is computed really fast. If I run the below code (basically the above extracted to a stub file and with a even larger dataframe and window size), the debugger can run that with no issue as well.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
from time import time 
...
# some random code to increase memory usage.
...
p = np.zeros((10*365*24*60,7))
t = time()
q = sliding_window_view(p,(24*60,7))
print(time()-t)
end =  1 # break point
from guppy import hpy
h = hpy()
print(h.heap())
```

When checked using guppy, the original code used about 100 MB and the stub file used more. So it doesnt seem to be a memory issue.

Comment: When software behaves weirdly, it is time to restart it

Comment: @PetrL. I restarted my computer and made a copy of my conda environment, it didnt seem to make a difference.